# Trying to get a password from decompiled Visual Basic .exe - can't decipher the assembly language

Tags: assembly, vb6

This is my first time ever posting here - please be gentle. I get a lot of useful tips from this site when I search Google for problems unrelated, and it seems like everyone here has a pretty good idea of what's going on.

I recently took over as the shipping manager for a small company that uses a proprietary software to manage inflow and outflow. There is a Special Edit button that asks for a password to make critical changes, and the previous person didn't pass the info along out of spite.

I used VB Decompiler Pro to decompile the executable, but it looks like it came out in assembly code, and I can't seem to figure out where it's referencing the correct password. We have the source code for an older version of the software, but the password listed in the old code is not the same as the current, which had its source code deleted.

Any help locating the password would be extremely appreciated.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click() '519FD0
  loc_00519FF5: var_8 = &H403058
  loc_0051A041: var_28 = 9
  loc_0051A052: var_60 = &H52A090
  loc_0051A059: var_68 = &H4008
  loc_0051A060: var_48 = Ucase(&H52A090)
  loc_0051A06A: Var_Ret_1 = (Ucase(vbObject) = var_48)
  loc_0051A076: var_9C = Var_Ret_1
  loc_0051A097: If Var_Ret_1 = 0 Then GoTo loc_0051A12F
  loc_0051A0A7: var_68 = 11
  loc_0051A0AA: eax = var_48 Or FFFFFFFFh
  loc_0051A0B7: var_60 = var_48 Or FFFFFFFFh
  loc_0051A0CA: esi+34h."canSpEdit" = var_5C
  loc_0051A0F5: var_AC = &H52AA00
  loc_0051A0FB: Set var_18 = Me
  loc_0051A109: Global.Unload var_18
  loc_0051A12F: 
  loc_0051A139: var_50 = 80020004h
  loc_0051A13C: var_40 = 80020004h
  loc_0051A13F: var_30 = 80020004h
  loc_0051A151: var_60 = "Password Incorrect"
  loc_0051A158: var_68 = 8
  loc_0051A15F: var_28 = "Password Incorrect"
  loc_0051A177: MsgBox var_28, 48
  loc_0051A18F: call 0052AA00h(00000004h, var_28, 10, 10, 10, 0052AA00h, 004137ECh, 00000010h, 00000003h)
  loc_0051A19B: var_68 = 11
  loc_0051A1BD: Me.SaveProp.%StkVar2 = var_5C
  loc_0051A1CB: GoTo loc_0051A1F2
  loc_0051A1F1: Exit Sub
  loc_0051A1F2: Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to push the original (compiled) file through a hex editor to get the password and you'll need to know where the password string is located. This may work for straightforward text, but if the password is encrypted you're going to have a world of pain. I can't remember for sure, but I suspect there is a hex dump utility with VB.

Comment: What happens if you try `5415056` as a password? (It is decimal for hex `&H52A090`).

Comment: That's not assembly code it's almost valid VB6 code - try it in the VB6 IDE and you'll see.

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov I think you have it right. You should submit it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you strip down irrelevant parts of code, you'll end up with the following:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Var_Ret_1 = (Ucase(vbObject) = Ucase(&H52A090))
  'Zero means False
  If Var_Ret_1 = 0 Then GoTo some_obscure_label
  Global.Unload Me
some_obscure_label: 
  'Inform user that supplied password is incorrect
End Sub
```

From here it's relatively easy to see that the only case when execution doesn't jump to notification about incorrect password is when `vbObject` equals hex number `&H52A090` (or `5415056` in decimal).

Code excerpt in the question doesn't show what `vbObject` actually is. Assuming that `vbObject` (or value of its default property) is user supplied password, `5415056` is the magic value you are after.